# How can i split one row into serval row ? using a linq 'UNION ALL'

Tags: asp.net, linq

#### 1. Context:

Client call Joe cause his apps need to print "the bill".(~15years ago)
But "bill" have different information depending on client type.

There are 3 types of client: ( a=1 , b=2 , c=4).
And a client can be a combinaison of those types. So it's a `bitfield`.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   type   is_SendA   is_SendB   is_SendC   is_PayedA   is_PayedB   is_PayedC |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  01    1      true        true       true      true        false       false
  02    2      false       true       true      false       true        false
  03    4      false       false      false     false       false       true
  04    3      true        false      false     true        false       false
  05    3      true        true       true      false       true        false
  06    5      false       true       true      false       false       true
  07    5      false       false      false     true        false       false
  08    6      true        false      false     false       true        false
  09    7      true        true       true      false       false       true
```

Type : Is a `bitfield`.
Is_SendA B C : Hold the same information, but for the different type as they can be different.
is_PayedA B C : Hold the same information

All the information of the paper are multipliate by the number of type.

#### 2. What do we Need:

As Killing Joe is not an option, neither is a drop database. 
The expected result is the following :

```
ID   type   is_Send    is_Payed
09    1       true      false
09    2       true      false
09    4       true      true
```

The idea is to make linq generate something like this:

```
SELECT   Id, 1 AS Type
        , is_SendA AS Is_Send
        , is_PayedA AS Is_Payed
WHERE    Id = 9
        AND Type & 1 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT    Id, 2 AS Type
          , is_SendB AS Is_Send
          , is_PayedB AS Is_Payed
WHERE     Id = 9
          AND Type & 2 = 2

UNION ALL

SELECT    Id, 4 AS Type
          , is_SendB AS Is_Send
          , is_PayedB AS Is_Payed
WHERE     Id = 9
          AND Type & 4 = 4
```

Why do we need this ? Because Right now to get the Paper Id=9 Type=A, We have to write down 35 columns name.
With a something able to display a content like show before a simple `where id= and type=` will give the correct result. And a grid able to display one type would be able to display an other type as the column name will now be the same.

*Fun fact*:
There is more than 90 column in the table. Only 3 are unique everyting else is duplicate for types.
While writing columns name, Joe experiences with naming convention. and some times he just miss type them.

*Nota bene*:
First, This is not for code shaming. The number of column are here to indicate the complexity that will have the implementation of some solution you may comes with.
Second, The fact that There is different naming convention explain that there is no way to simply generate the column name.

Comment: Can you provide sample "myView" data and the expected output?

Comment: So... is this just a list of strings that we're looking at? Or is it a POCO? If it is a POCO, can you share the class definition with us (just the relevant parts)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can use [Enumerable.SelectMany()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) method to unfold your row into multiple rows like this:

```
var results = myView.SelectMany(v =>
{
    var list = new List<Tuple<int,string>>();
    if((v.DEV_Dest & 1) == 1)
        list.Add(Tuple.Create(v.Id,v.DataA));
    if((v.DEV_Dest & 2) == 2)
        list.Add(Tuple.Create(v.Id, v.DataB));
    if((v.DEV_Dest & 3) == 3)
        list.Add(Tuple.Create(v.Id, v.DataC));
    return list;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: In fact its an old database. And instead of creating a new table with some link .
Few row prefixed by Something, have been create every time a new type of user was discovered. Thats quite epic!
So i have 5 fixed row that thver change an 21 prefixed ( 7 type * 3 row )

Comment: @PierreLebon, unfortunately it's not very clear what you have and what you want outputted. Can you please give an example of input and desired output? You can edit the question in order to provide the example.